# Approximation of sum of i.i.d.s using CLT

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ be i.i.d. $ \sim binom(p)$ (so it hits $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ otherwise). I am interested in understanding the pdf $f = f_N$ of the sum $Y = Y_N = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.

Symbolically but abstractly, it is just $f_N(L) = p^L (1-p)^{N-L}$ which maximizes around $L = pN$. However, without help of numerical method, this form isn't so helpful for a few questions. For example, how concentrated is the function around $pN$? More concretely, find the least $\Delta$ such that $$\sum_{i \in [pN -\Delta, pN+\Delta]} f_N(i) \quad> \,0.95.$$

The central limit theorem (CLT) seems to be a useful tool here for this question as it heuristically says that $f$ appoximates a normal distribution. However, I'm not sure if we can use it directly: In formal term, what CLT really asserts is

$$\frac{Y}{\sqrt{N}} - p\sqrt{N} \to \mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p))$$

in distribution.

**Question**: How do I use CLT to understand the pdf of $Y$, instead of just the left-hand-side? In particular, can one quickly estimate $\Delta$ using CLT?

Comment: Better to use lowercase for non-random variables. Each $X_i$ has a Bernoulli distribution (a binomial distribution with parameters $1$ and $p$ with mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$).  $Y$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$; being a discrete random variable, it does not have a density.

Comment: If you are going to use a normal approximation then can use the variance and might say you want your $\Delta \approx 1.96 \sqrt{np(1-p)}$ since from the cdf of a standard normal $\Phi(1.96)-\Phi(-1.96) \approx 0.95$, thought this will only be an approximation

Comment: @Henry Do you mean that since $Y_n$ has mean being $np$ and variance being $\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$, we can pretend that it is a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$?

Comment: $Y$ does not have a normal distribution, but the central limit theorem says that $\frac{Y-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ as $n$ increases.  That suggests that in some circumstances (typically $np$ and $n(1-p)$ both large enough, and not looking just at the extreme tails) the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal N(np,np(1-p))$ may provide a reasonable approximation to  the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, though you should perhaps use continuity corrections.

Comment: This is what I supposed at first. But the convergence is pointwise ("in distribution"), so I don't think that's possible. Still, in many heuristic arguments people still believe such method is viable, thus the question.

Comment: Pointwise convergence of the distribution means that for any $k$ with $0<k<1$, you have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb P\left(\frac{Y-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \le k \right) = \Phi(k)$, so for that $k$ there will a big enough $n$ to be as close as you like.  But this does not tell you how big $n$ needs to be (it will typically depend on how close you want to be and on  $k$ and on the original distribution) and so when you get a good approximation